# Mandatory? use of a different Delimiter for a StoredProcedure in MySql

Tags: java, mysql, database, jdbc, io

From [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/storedprocedures.html#create_jdbc_mysql) oracle java tutorial:

> In MySQL, statements in a stored procedure are separated by
>   semicolons. However, a different delimiter is required to end the
>   create procedure statement.

I have been using stored procedures for a while and I have never needed to use a pipe as delimiter to end the create procedure thing.

Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

It's just a specified delimiter between SQL statements. You could use a different character as a delimiter. If you use only one statement with JDBC it's even could be omitted.

> This example uses the pipe (|) character; you can use another
>   character (or more than one character). This character that separates
>   statements is defined in the delimiter attribute in the Ant target
>   that calls this script.
>
> Alternatively, you can use the DELIMITER SQL statement to specify a
>   different delimiter character.